# Bootloop on Windows after Installing Ubuntu

Tags: boot, multi-boot, grub2

I can't get past the "Startup Repair", it just sends it into a continuous loop.
Here is the SrtTrail from Windows, I'm assuming it was from installing GRUB.

```
Startup Repair diagnosis and repair log
--------------------------- Last successful boot time: ‎10/‎15/‎2016 5:53:45 AM (GMT) Number of repair attempts: 3

Session details
--------------------------- System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0 Windows directory = D:\WINDOWS AutoChk Run = 0 Number of root causes = 1

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Check for updates Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: System disk test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Disk failure diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Disk metadata test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 47 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Target OS test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Volume content check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 16 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Boot manager diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: System boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Event log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 16 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Internal state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Boot status test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Setup state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 1046 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Registry hives test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 3782 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Windows boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Root cause found: 
--------------------------- Boot critical file D:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\WRkrn.sys is corrupt.

---------------------------
--------------------------- Session details
--------------------------- System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0 Windows directory = D:\WINDOWS AutoChk Run = 0 Number of root causes = 1

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Check for updates Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: System disk test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Disk failure diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Disk metadata test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 62 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Target OS test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Volume content check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 10766 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Boot manager diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: System boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Event log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 94 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Internal state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 47 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Boot status test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 15 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Setup state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 1219 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Registry hives test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 3953 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Windows boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Root cause found: 
--------------------------- Boot critical file D:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\WRkrn.sys is corrupt.

---------------------------
--------------------------- Session details
--------------------------- System Disk = \Device\Harddisk0 Windows directory = D:\WINDOWS AutoChk Run = 0 Number of root causes = 1

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Check for updates Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: System disk test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Disk failure diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 79 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Disk metadata test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 62 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Target OS test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 78 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Volume content check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 11031 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Boot manager diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: System boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Event log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 94 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Internal state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 47 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Boot status test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 31 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Setup state check Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 1266 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Registry hives test Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 3953 ms

Test Performed: 
--------------------------- Name: Windows boot log diagnosis Result: Completed successfully. Error code =  0x0 Time taken = 0 ms

Root cause found: 
--------------------------- Boot critical file d:\windows\system32\drivers\wrkrn.sys is corrupt.

Repair action: File repair Result: Failed. Error code =  0x2 Time taken = 9406 ms

---------------------------
---------------------------
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. You have errors in your Windows system partition that were caused by not shrinking properly said partition or a number of other possibilities even with Windows as a single OS: https://community.webroot.com/t5/Webroot-for-Business/windows-system32-drivers-wrkrn-sys/td-p/266416 (just an example).